# Is it possible to copy purchase orders from site to an updated version of the same site?

Tags: commerce, importing-exporting

We have this site with Drupal Commerce and Commerce Registration Integration. The only "Product" is a single registration. 4 months ago the site was copied to development and that copy was completely revamped. Recently, I was tasked with putting the revamped development site into production. Initially, I wanted to copy the changes from the development site into production. However, I was advised the changes were so extensive, it would be weeks of work and the client wanted the revamped site live the next day.

So, the revamped site site is now live and I have to find a way to get the 95 registrations that occurred in the last 4 months from the original site to the revamped one.

Yes, this transition has been handled badly. However, if anyone has any suggestions I would be grateful.